# Cómo se pasa un json externo a variable local, con Javascript [NO JQUERY]

Tags: javascript

[JSON](http://example.com/file/external.json)

```
[
{"fruta":"manzana","postre":"postre de manzana"},
{"fruta":"platano","postre":"shi sheñol"}
]
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que el JSON está en un servidor, y quieres bajarlo?

Comment: No, no bajarlo al equipo del cliente, sino que tomar el json del servidor, y usarlo como variable en el documento local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cargando el fichero con XMLHttpRequest debe funcionarte

```
var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
Httpreq.open("GET","http://example.com/file/external.json",false);
Httpreq.send(null);
var variable_local = Httpreq.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Con node se requiere como un módulo cualquiera:

```
const menu = require ('./menu.json');
```

Y lo recorres como un array normal y corriente:

```
menu.forEach((item) =>
  console.log('fruta: '+item.fruta+', postre:'+item.fruta)
);
//fruta: manzana, postre: postre de manzana
//fruta: platano, postre: shi sheñol
```